# In Julia, can reserved keywords be aliased with letter-only tokens?

Tags: julia, alias, reserved-words

In C, one can easily define a macro to achieve such a thing, because the macro system is a dumb text substitution.

```
#define se fi
se ( true )
  print( "jes!" );
```

In contrast, Julia with its syntactic macro system gives far more metaprogramming power. However, implementing an alias of a reserved word seems far less trivial, if possible.

So the question is basically, does Julia allow to end up with a code like

```
se ( vera )
  liniu( "jes!" )
hop
```

that would be seamlessly interpreted as

```
if ( true )
  println( "jes!" )
end
```

In particular, the sought solution should not end up with a `@se` and so on, while still allow equivalent backtrace facilities for debugging code.

Comment: Macro calls must always be prepended with a `@`. This is a deliberate design choice to clearly signal where "code rewrite magic" happens. So, the answer is no, by design.

Comment: Ok, so one can not use affectation of a macro expansion for this I guess. Are they other builtin facilities that would enable to achieve the specified goal?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: I tried something like this a few years ago, because I wanted to teach programming in Spanish to small children with no English knowledge. At the time I used the JuliaParser package: [Julieta: spanish version of Julia!](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/julia-dev/Vu6zyCPkkFs), which is not maintained anymore. Julia has changed a lot since then, but now it sports a stable release, maybe it's a good time to try again. For full i18n support changes in main Julia would be needed, for things like errors, stack traces, documentation, etc.

Comment: I created [Julia-i18n](https://github.com/Julia-i18n) back then with this idea in mind, and also to setup infrastructure to aid in internationalization and localization of documentation, the web site and Julia itself. Work, family and a constantly evolving Julia at the time made me step back for a while though. Here is another example I like [LispSyntax](https://github.com/swadey/LispSyntax.jl) this one uses the [ParserCombinator](https://github.com/andrewcooke/ParserCombinator.jl) package, which seems to be updated for Julia 1.0. If you develop something like that I would love to see it! :)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much @SalchiPapa. Internationalization of the programming language in a seamless experience is indeed the driving motivation behind this question. I'll look closely at the links you provided.